# Find the determinant by using elementary row operations

Tags: matrices

I'm having a problem finding the determinant of the following matrix using elementary row operations. I know the determinant is -15 but confused on how to do it using the elementary row operations.
Here is the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 &  3 & 10   \\ 1 & 2 & -2   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Note that the determinant of a lower (or upper) triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal elements. Using this fact, we want to create a triangular matrix out of your matrix
\begin{bmatrix} 2 &  3 & 10   \\ 1 & 2 & -2   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix}
So, I will start with the last row and subtract it from the second row to get
\begin{bmatrix} 2 &  3 & 10   \\ 0 & 1 & 1   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix}
Now, I want to get rid of the $2$ in the first row. I thus multiply the last row by $2$ and subtract it from the first row to obtain:
\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  1 & 16   \\ 0 & 1 & 1   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix}
Finally, I subtract the second row from the first one to obtain
\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  0 & 15   \\ 0 & 1 & 1   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix}
We now have
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} 2 &  3 & 10   \\ 1 & 2 & -2   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  0 & 15   \\ 0 & 1 & 1   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I will transform the RHS matrix to an upper diagonal matrix. I can exchange the first and the last rows. Exchanging any two rows changes the sign of the determinant, and therefore
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} 2 &  3 & 10   \\ 1 & 2 & -2   \\ 1 & 1 & -3   \end{bmatrix} = -\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 & 1   \\  0 &  0 & 15    \end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix on the RHS is now an upper triangular matrix and its determinant is the product of its diagonal elements, which is $15$. With the minus sign, the $\det$ of our initial matrix is thus $-15$.